# Use the linux 'templates' folder to make folder templates

Tags: templates

I take my course notes in LaTeX and I have a base folder style I set up that contains an intro page and a lecture stream. In this case it's trivial to create but sometimes the situation could be more complex.

Is there any way to put a folder into the `templates` folder and create that folder? If I create the folder when I go to `create document`, it lets me go into the folder and select documents, but I can't create the folder.

Is there any way to set the folder as a creatable file? Maybe if I don't have permission to read its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [New Folder from Template](https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/nautilus-new-folder-from-template) extension for Nautilus?